# Nifi expression language If else statement

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a use case where I have two attributes in my flowfile, and in my fetchdistributedcachemap processor, I need to test `if uuid is empty then use device_id` are they any way to do this in nifi expression language ? Or do I need to do an updateAttribute ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the [`replaceEmpty`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#replaceempty) function.

```
${uuid:replaceEmpty(${device_id})}
```

Unlike the examples in the docs that use literal strings, you would need to reference your other attribute as a nested expression like `${device_id}` shown above.